# Crystal Reports - formula of full name to initial name

Tags: crystal-reports

How to display full name in short form like S.M.John in Crystal Reports.
Ex: Database value = Sammual Mbark John.

Need to display =>  S.M.John

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Considering your full name can have 2, 3, n names, I think this formula will do the job:

```
Stringvar result := "";

Local Numbervar i;

Stringvar Array output:= Split({Your.Field}, ' ');

for i := 1 to ubound(output) do (

    if i <> ubound(output) then
        result := result + left(output[i], 1) + "."
    else 
        result := result + output[i]
);

result
```

Example and results:

1) "This Is My Test Name" will be "T.I.M.T.Name"

2) "Kurt Donald Cobain" will be "K.D.Cobain"

3) "Barack Hussein Obama" will be "B.H.Obama"

4) "Sammual Mbark John" will be "S.M.John"

Comment: This will work in a pinch, but names like Ludwig van Beethoven will be problematic.  The best way to avoid these types of issues is to fix the back-end database so that first, middle, and last names (and their prefixes and suffixes) are stored as separate fields.  And there are a large number of prefixed last names when you start getting names from France, Italy, Germany, and many other countries.

Comment: @N.karunarathna you're welcome. Could you then accept the answer as correct, so other people can use it too if necessary?